# How to inherit all properties of a Control with a TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I am trying make my own version of a control, say a `TextBox`, to which I want to add some custom UI. I am want to inherit from this class, so that the user can still call my special text box in the same way he would call a regular one. I have got the following:

```
// MySpecialTextBox.cs

public class MySpecialTextBox : TextBox
{
    static MySpecialTextBox () { }   

    /* Some special properties */     
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MySpecialTextBox}">        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MySpecialTextBox}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="3" Fill="Pink" /> <!-- My own fancy lay-out -->
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>         <!-- This text box should 'inherit' ALL the properties from the caller -->
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My problem here is that now, the `TextBox` only gets the properties you explicitly set in this template, in this case, only `Text`. I would like to also bind to `Background`, `Foreground`, and every other possible property. Obviously I could do something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MySpecialTextBox}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="3" Fill="Pink" />
           <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" 
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                     AcceptsReturn="{TemplateBinding AcceptsReturn}"
                     AllowDrop="{TemplateBinding AllowDrop}"
                     <!-- ETCETERA -->
                   />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

listing all properties, but that feels horribly inefficient. Is there a way to bind to the entire parent in one go?

Comment: No there isn't... you have to set every property that you want to use.

Comment: Really? :-( Well, I guess a negative answer is also an answer. No work-arounds either?

Comment: ALthough you create your own TextBox class it does not differ from ordinary situation. You override default template and in order to acquire any value from parent's property you need to do TemplateBinding.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to place another `TextBox` element in a template for another `TextBox`. What you should do is always edit the default template for a control when you are overriding its template.

So, in the default template for a `TextBox` you will find the following element:

```
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Border>
```

This border is responsible for drawing the `TextBox`. If you use this part instead of your inner `TextBox` you will have all other `TextBox` properties "Inherited".

**Edit:**

The full template should be:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MySpecialTextBox}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:MySpecialTextBox}">
                 <StackPanel>
                     <Rectangle Width="100" Height="3" Fill="Pink" />
                     <!-- My own fancy lay-out -->
                     <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                         <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                     </Border>
                 </StackPanel>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on this a little bit? I don't entirely understand where this code is and/or can be editted. Cause in the TextBox Style there is no Property called `Border` that can be editted (only `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush`).

Comment: In your template instead of using another TextBox you should use the `ScrollViewer` with special name "PART_ContentHost". See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

A `TemplateBinding` is an optimized form of a standard `Binding` and roughly equivalent to using a `Binding` with the `RelativeSource` property set to `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`. As such and like standard `Binding`s, can only be set on a single property. From the [`TemplateBindingExtension` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatebindingextension.aspx) page on MSDN:

> You use `TemplateBinding` in template to bind to **a value** on the control the template is applied to.

From the [`TemplateBinding` Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) page on MSDN:

> ... `TemplateBinding` has only one settable property...

This means that we cannot supply more than one property name to it and so it only works with a single property. Unfortunately, there is no convenient `SuperTemplateBinding` that affects all properties, but even if there were, I can't imagine any easy way to map which properties should bind to which template properties. The answer is therefore 'No, there is no shortcut to inheriting property values from a templated parent control'.

Comment: `TemplateBinding` and `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent` are not same. First gets resolved at compile time and other at run time.